# Get the last tr under the class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I get the last `tr` after the class `group` like this

```html
<table id="compareTable">
  <tr class="group"><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>One</td></tr> <!--Get this one-->
  <tr class="group"><td>a</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td></tr>
  <tr><td>two</td></tr> <!--Get this two-->
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working  Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42462/)**.

Could be done using `nextUntil` like :

```
$('#compareTable tr.group').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil( "tr.group", "tr" ).last().css( "font-weight", "bold" );
});
```

```js
$('#compareTable tr.group').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil( "tr.group", "tr" ).last().css( "font-weight", "bold" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="compareTable">
  <tr class="group">
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <!--Get this one-->
  <tr class="group">
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <!--Get this two-->
</table>
```

Comment: This gives you row "a" - which is the last group row.  OP is expecting rows "one" *and* "two".

Answer (score 0):

[View Demo Here](http:////jsfiddle.net/vjyramesh/eofzr5uv)

There is nothing to do with the jquery. It is mainly on the dom selector.

With the below code we can able to select the last tr after a particular class.

table#compareTable .group ~ tr:last-of-type

Comment: Not sure why you think this has nothing do to with jquery - where would you use the "code" that you've provided?  In a jquery selector by some chance?

Comment: This will only give you the last row "two", not both "one" and "two" rows.

Comment: in ever class has a last tr right? In Jquery how do i get one and two using jquery selector